# Text file not opening on Visual Studio 2017. It opens on Dev C++ though

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "string"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   fstream room_type;
   string line;
   room_type.open("rooms.txt", ios::in);
   while (!room_type.eof())
   {
      getline(room_type, line);
      cout << line << endl;
   }
    room_type.close();
}
```

I have tried giving the path.
I've tried saving both .cpp file and .text file in the same location.
I've tried everything I can with my knowledge + googled a lot. There's nothing that solves this problem.

Comment: If you want to use relative paths, know that by default in VS the *Working Directory* for your executable is $(ProjectDir) (I always change it to $(OutDir), which is the directory of the exe itself). You can change this by going to the Project properties in the "Debugging" section.

Comment: where is "rooms.txt" stored? Where are you running your program from? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It's not about the txt file being at the location than the cpp file, but as the exe. Change the run location for debug.

Comment: try full path to file.

Comment: *There's nothing that solves this problem* -- Just supply the *full path* of the file to open.  If the file exists, you will see it open the file.  Then from there, figure out why supplying just the name does not work.  As others already pointed out, using a relative file name means different things to different environments.

Comment: In Visual Studio the default working directory when debugging or just executing in the IDE is the location of the project not the location of executable like it is on many other IDEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the directory where the mentioned file is present:

```
room_type.open("C:\\which_directory\\rooms.txt", ios::in);
```

You might run it without mentioning the directory, but in that case the executable should be located in the same directory as the file itself, which might depend on your development environment.

Comment: IT WORKED! I didn't know you had to put double backslash for the path. I was using single because that's what I saw on another site. Thank you.